# Clicking into a file takes me to a different place

Tags: folder

When I click into a folder, I am taken to a whole different place in SharePoint files instead of inside that folder.  What to do?

Comment: Is the folder inside a Document Library or List?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/52689)